# Should I store Firebase credentials in iCloud?

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, icloud

**TL/DR:** We're using Firebase in our app, and we'd like to sync the Firebase credentials between the different iOS devices of a user. To achieve that, we're considering saving the credentials in iCloud. This seems a bit unusual, since most apps use either iCloud or Firebase as their serverless backend. **Is this a feasible approach? Are there any particular disadvantages?**

**Long story:**

We're designing a Firebase app, which transparently creates a user account in Firebase as soon as the user signs in. The user does not notice being signed in. We just generate a random mail address like 0fc7b18ea7e@my-app.com, as well as a random password, and store those credentials on the user's device (let's call those "anonymous accounts").

Later, the user can choose to create an account in the GUI, at which point we just change the mail address and the password to the credentials entered by the user. This way, the user's account becomes a non-anonymous account.

Now we'd like to sync the credentials between the users' devices. Say the user has an iPad and an iPhone, and they start the app for the first time on the iPhone. An anonymous account is created for them, and they begin to use the app. Later, they start the app on the iPad. We want them to be signed in to the same account as on the iPhone, even if they don't specify any credentials.

Why do we have this auth design? It is critical for our app that users can just open the app and start right away, without having to sign up to anything. Moreover, it's also crucial that users who use more than one device use the same account. For the anonymous user, this can only work if the credentials are shared between the devices in some way.

Comment: Did you consider using [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) for the initial account? That would save you having to store the credentials.

Comment: "We want them to be signed in to the same account as on the iPhone, even if they don't specify any credentials." If they don't sign in in any way on the second account, how do you know what existing user they are, or whether they are even an existing user?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We would know their credentials if they are stored in their iCloud account. That's the whole idea: The first sign-in creates the credentials and puts them in iCloud. Then when the user signs in on the other device, the credentials are already there, because they are shared via iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been solved with this update of the iOS SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/6924